# Displaying database valuees obtained through a RESTful webservice in a JSP pag

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jsp

I am implementing a messanger using Jax-Rs. I have a client application which use the implemented API. within the database message_id,message,date, sender fields are stored. I need to display these values within a div of jsp page of the client application.

client.jsp

```
    <form action="ClientServlet" method ="post"  onclick="onTechIdChange();"></form>
         <div id="uploadSuggest" class="center-block">
         <div id="suggestHeading" class="row">
                    <h4 class="textTitle center-block"> Messages  </h4>
                </div>      
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
           <a  id="btn_padding" href="#download" class="btn btn-image pull-left" onclick="onTechIdChange();">Create Profile</a>
           <p>   </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>

    </div>
      </div>  
    </section>

    <script>

    function onTechIdChange()   {  

          var urlPath = "http://localhost:8081/messanger/webapi/messages" ;
          $.ajax({
           url : urlPath,
           dataType : "json",
           cache: false,
           type : 'GET',
           success : function(result) {
                var details = result[0];
                var name;
                for(name in details)
                    {
                    dispatchEvent(event)
                    }
                alert(details.sender);
           },
           error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('An error occurred at the server');
           }
          });
          function display(msg) {
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                p.innerHTML = msg;
                document.body.appendChild(p);
              }
         } 
    </script>

Through this code nothing is displayed in the div. But values are printed in the tomcat console which ensures that all the methods within API are working properly. Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance


UPDATE

I Updated the javascript code snippet. But nothing is displayed inside the <p> tag



  var urlPath = "http://localhost:8081/messanger/webapi/messages" ;
  $.ajax({
   url : urlPath,
   dataType : "json",
   cache: false,
   type : 'GET',
   success : function(result) {
        var details = result[0];
        var name;
        for(name in details.sender)
            {
            display(name);
            }
        alert(details.sender);
   },
   error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
    alert('An error occurred at the server');
   }
  });
  function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
 } 

This is the section with the <p>

    <form action="ClientServlet" method ="post"  onclick="onTechIdChange();"></form>
         <div id="uploadSuggest" class="center-block">
         <div id="suggestHeading" class="row">
                    <h4 class="textTitle center-block"> Messages  </h4>
                </div>      
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
           <a  id="btn_padding" href="#download" class="btn btn-image pull-left" onclick="onTechIdChange();">Create Profile</a>
           <p>   </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>

    </div>
      </div>  
    </section>
```

If somebody knows a tutorial regarding this can you upload a link?

Comment: Where you are calling the display function?

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629621/calling-java-method-from-html-without-using-a-servlet/35632063#35632063

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling the display function that add the values to the DOM.

```
  for(name in details){
   display(name)
  }
```

Also I am not sure that your parser is correct

```
  success : function(result) {
            var details = result[0];  -- Extract the first value of response
            var name;
            for(name in details)  --- should be an array as well
                {
                dispatchEvent(event) -- I think here you need to call print function
                }
            alert(details.sender); -- If details.sender have the details probably the 
                                       iteration should be for(name in details.sender)
       },
```

Also I reconsider the use of  `$.ajax`, probably use `$.get` is better and also, use jsp I dont think is needed use a simple html with a javascript.