# How to extract key:value from html

Tags: java, html, json, jsp, servlets

I have the following String data that is send from a servlet to the index page.

```
{  "hits" : {"hits" : [ { "_source":{"ID":"123","Status":"false","Name":"ABC_123","Date":"2010-08-16T11:07:48"}    }, {      "_source":{"ID":"124","Status":"false","Name":"ABC_678","Date":"2010-08-16T12:00:12"}    }, {      "_source":{"ID":"125","Status":"true","Name":"FGH_122","Date":"2010-08-16T12:01:48"}    }, {      "_source":{"ID":"126","Status":"false","Name":"TYT_333","Date":"2010-08-16T12:06:48"}    }, {      "_source":{"ID":"127","Status":"false","Name":"CVF_230","Date":"2010-08-16T12:07:18"}    }, {      "_source":{"ID":"128","Status":"true","Name":"AWE_101","Date":"2010-08-16T12:03:48"}    }, {      "_source":{"ID":"129","Status":"true","Name":"WEC_299","Date":"2010-08-16T12:07:29"}    } ]  }}
```

I want to parse the data and see data in an arraylist format like:

```
{ID:"123", "Name":"ABC_123"}
{ID:"124", "Name":"ABC_678"}
```

etc...

Any idea on how I can achieve this either from the client side or from server? Please advice.. Thanks

Comment: I think it will much simpler if your accessing your json obj in client side JS.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629621/calling-java-method-from-html-without-using-a-servlet/35632063#35632063.in your code snippet i think u miss the `Iterator` try this sample.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338943/read-json-string-in-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array and add objects to it before you return them to the JSP.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0 ; i < hitsArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jObject = hitsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    arr.put(jObject.get("_source"));         
}    

request.setAttribute("jsonObject", arr);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `ArrayList` of `HashMap`s before the loop, and add the data there.
Like this

```
...rest of your code...
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();            
for (int i = 0 ; i < hitsArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jObject = hitsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject source = jObject.get("_source");
    Iterator<String> it = source.keys();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = it.next();
        data.put(key, source.getString(key));
    }
    list.add(data);
}
request.setAttribute("jsonObject", list);
... rest of your code...
```

Updated code for the jettison, but I would recommend to switch to javax.json;

Comment: Can you please tel me what do you mean by " ....copy data from _source to data map..." ? Thanks.

Comment: I am getting "The constructor HashMap<String,String>(Object) is undefined"

Comment: what is `JSONObject`? Which library are you using? If you would use `JsonObject` from JEE it would work.

Comment: I am using "import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;"

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I am still getting few errors. The code by Roman worked. Thanks for your time.